# How to parse data from Fiddler .saz file using python

Tags: python, parsing, fiddler

I want to write a script, which extract some specific response data from Fiddler .saz file, using python. I found a simple   [script](https://github.com/hekinami/sazparser), which extract some basic meta  information about the  .saz file. But I need to print the value of server response  (or just whole server response)  if it exist in this .saz file.

I tried to write this, but I don't know how. Ewery time  I got some error message.

```
└──╼ $python3 sazparser.py 1.saz 
  File "sazparser.py", line 272
    order_id += sfilelist.order_id
           ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block


def main():
    import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='saz file parser')
    parser.add_argument('filename', help='saz file name')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    sazfile = SazFile(args.filename)
    order_id = None
    for  num, sfilelist in enumerate(sazfile.sfilelist):
if 'order_id' in sfilelist.read():
    order_id += sfilelist.order_id
         print('order_id')





if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I want to show every server request in output, which contains word "order_id".

Answer (score -1):

Try to fix your indentation

```
import argparse
def main():

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='saz file parser')
    parser.add_argument('filename', help='saz file name')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    sazfile = SazFile(args.filename)
    order_id = None
    for  num, sfilelist in enumerate(sazfile.sfilelist):
        for sffile in sffilelist:
            print(sffile.read())






if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you, but I got new error instead of previous: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: What is the content of sfilelist?

Comment: I think it's an arrow  
 def sfilelist(self):
   self._sfilelist = [
     x for x in self.zipfile.namelist()
     if x.startswith('raw') and x.endswith('_s.txt')
    ]
   return self._sfilelist

Comment: Here is a full code https://github.com/hekinami/sazparser/blob/master/sazparser.py

Comment: I've updated my answer. What's the content of sffile?